# Printing result of mySQL query with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working SQL statement that returned correct results when I checked it on MAMP.

```
SELECT `questions`.`questionID` AS question, `questions`.`questionText`, 
       `questions`.`categoryID`,`answers`.`answerID`,`answers`.`answerText`,
       `answers`.`isTrue`
FROM `questions`,`answers`
WHERE `questions`.`questionID` = `answers`.`questionID`
```

But I can't figure out how to print the output with php. Please help. This is the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","Theory");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `questions`.`questionID` AS question, `questions`.`questionText`, `questions`   .`categoryID`, `answers`.`answerID`,`answers`.`answerText`,`answers`.`isTrue`
                                 FROM `questions`,`answers`
                                 WHERE `questions`.`questionID` = `answers`.`questionID`");

    if (!$result)
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
       echo "{";
       echo "{" . $row['questions'.'questionID'] . "}";   //this is not the full print
       echo "{" . $row['questions'.'questionText'] . "}"; //just for chaking
       echo "}";
   }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

</body>
</head>
```

I get:"{{}{}}{{}{}}{{}{}}{{}{}}{{}{}}{{}{}}{{}{}}{{}{}}" echoed.

Comment: Turn on error reporting, use error handlers and then come back. Also, learn about explicit SQL syntax.

Comment: `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))` -> `if (!$result)`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I am just a beginner, so I'll appreciate some references.

Comment: @Luda [Error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), [error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're executing a query again inside your if condition... But the `$sql` query is empty because the variable is not defined!

replace `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))` with  `if (!$result)` since you have already executed the query in the rows above.

EDIT to answer the question's comments:

when you're fetching the resulting array, you don't need to specify the table alias but just the column name OR the column alias if present.

Try this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "{";
   echo "{" . $row['questionID'] . "}";   //this is not the full print
   echo "{" . $row['questionText'] . "}"; //just for checking
   echo "}";
}
```

Comment: +1 since your comment was faster than my answer (I had to make sure that the returned value was FALSE in the documentation).

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia +1 to you too because your answer was nevertheless correct.

Answer (score 5):

`$sql` is aparently not set. You can do:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `questions`.`questionID` AS question, `questions`.`questionText`, `questions`   .`categoryID`, `answers`.`answerID`,`answers`.`answerText`,`answers`.`isTrue`
                             FROM `questions`,`answers`
                             WHERE `questions`.`questionID` = `answers`.`questionID`");

if (!$result)
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```